# Git [remote rejected] - cannot lock ref

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a local branch to GitHub [project I forked (ASP.Net/Docs)](https://github.com/spottedmahn/Docs) and I'm receiving the following error:

> mdepouw@my-awesome-pc MINGW64 ~/source/repos/GitHub/spottedmahn/aspnet/Docs (dev/test1)
>
> $ git push --set-upstream origin dev/test1
>
> Counting objects: 6, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 501 bytes | 501.00 KiB/s, done.
>
> Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 5 local objects.
>
> To https://github.com/spottedmahn/Docs.git
>    ! [remote rejected]     dev/test1 -> dev/test1 (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/dev/test1': 'refs/heads/dev' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/dev/test1')
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/spottedmahn/Docs.git'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there was a branch named `dev` in the repo I forked and I was trying to use `dev/test1`.

I **renamed** my **branch** to `dev2/test1` and the push succeeded.

---

When I inspected the branches in VS I noticed it.  I was also not allowed to check it out.

[image: check out conflict]

Comment: Git needs a better error message. Thanks for updating with answer!